# Determining if a number range overlaps others in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an input number range that goes from 5 to 100.

I also have:

- Number range 1 that goes from 40 to 56
- Number range 2 that goes from 299-490
- Number range 3 that goes from 1-400
- etc...

Each have "Start" numbers and "End" numbers in separate columns (D and E).

My input number range is dynamic - I want to be able to check, when I input numbers in the input number range (col A and B), that it overlaps or not with all others (1, 2, 3, ...)

**1-------A------B-----C------D------E**

**2**------5------100-----------40-----56

**3**-----TRUE----------------299---490

**4**------------------------------1-----400

I have tried this formula:
`in cell A3=SUMPRODUCT((A2<=E2:E4)*(B2>=D2:D4))>1`

I have also tried this formula: `=OR(AND(A1>=MIN(D1:D5),A1<=MAX(D1:D5)),AND(B1>=MIN(E1:E5),B1<=MAX(E1:E5)))`

But it only works if the starting value is 0. In the following image, it should show as "TRUE" because clearly, 1000 to 15000 overlaps with all of the ranges.

[image: example of it not working, this works when the first value is 0 though]

Comment: I'm not quite following. D holds starting range numbers. E holds ending range numbers. Correct? When you enter a value in A or B you want to know if that value is within one or more ranges? You want a TRUE or FALSE next to the value? To replace the value? This might be easier to understand with a screenshot from Excel.

Comment: @DavidRichardson Added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This formula won't give you TRUE result based on the data:

```
=OR(AND(A1>=MIN(D1:D5),A1<=MAX(D1:D5)),AND(B1>=MIN(E1:E5),B1<=MAX(E1:E5)))
```

A1 is below the lowest value in D1:D5 and B1 is larger than the largest value of E1:E5.

MIN(D1:D5) = 7850, which is larger than 1000, so this is FALSE.
MAX(E1:E5) = 14089, which is smaller than 15000, so this is also FALSE.

I'm assuming you want to check that the range of MIN(D1:D5):MAX(E1:E5) overlaps with the set of A1:B1. You're not looking for inclusion, but for any overlap, correct?

If so this will work:

```
=AND(A1 <= MAX(E$1:E$5), B1 >= MIN(D$1:D$5))
```

I started looking at inclusion rules for one set within another. It's too messy and complicated. So I looked at exclusion rules: If A1 is > than max value for the set, there can't be any overlap. Similarly, if B1 < than the minimum for the set, there can't be any overlap. That's all we need to check for. Once we rule out the exclusion set what is left must be the inclusion set.

This makes some assumptions you many want to check for:

```
A1 < B1
MIN(D1:D5) < MAX(E1:E5)
```

There's another potential issue here: Your number sets in D1:E1 to D5:E5 are non-contiguous. So you could end up with a range in A1:B1 that falls between these sets and should not return a TRUE result. For example, 10,000 in A1 and 10,500 in B1 does not fall within one of the sets in D1:E1 to D5:E5. So the function above will give false positives if you care about those gaps. They only way I can see to do this is to check A1:B1 against each set:

```
=OR(AND(A1 <= E$1, B1 >= D$1), AND(A1 <= E$2, B1 >= D$2), AND(A1 <= E$3, B1 >= D$3), AND(A1 <= E$4, B1 >= D$4), AND(A1 <= E$5, B1 >= D$5))
```

Using this function with 10,000 in A1 and 10,500 in B1 will return FALSE.

Hope this helps and that you get it figured out. This is a deceptively challenging problem.